# rkhunter warns about chkconfig

Tags: debian, chkconfig, rkhunter

I ran `rkhunter` and received the following warnings in its output:

```
$ rkhunter --update
$ rkhunter -c

...
...
...

Performing file properties checks
    /sbin/chkconfig                                          [ Warning ]
```

In the `/var/log/rkhunter.log`, it shows this message:

```
Warning: The command '/sbin/chkconfig' has been replaced by a script: /sbin/chkconfig: Perl script, ASCII text executable
```

Though I am on a Debian system and am aware of `update-rc.d`, I occasionally use `chkconfig` to configure services.

What does this warning mean? How serious is this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would think that this warning is harmless (assuming you have not been hacked or you haven't installed any suspicious packages), it seems that rkhunter thinks that scripts in /sbin are suspicious behaviour.

In fact, checked on a clean Ubuntu install I have here and `chkconfig` is indeed a script.

Comment: You meant `chkconfig is indeed a script` as opposed to a binary, right? Just trying to understand here. What is the difference?

Comment: Exactly; type `file /sbin/chkconfig` and see for yourself. The main difference is that a script is (generally) written in an interpreted language (bash, perl etc...) and a binary is the result of compiling a program (e.g. written in C); from an end-user (not a developer) point of view, there isn't much difference.

Comment: Since `/sbin` is supposed to have binaries in it, rkhunter threw a warning since it encountered a script rather than an executable. It makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're running Ubuntu, create (or edit) the file `/etc/rkhunter.conf.local` and add the following line.

```
PKGMGR=DPKG
```

This tells `rkhunter` to use the file hash info available via `dpkg`.