# Additional Examination to that of RkHunter False Flags

Tags: udev, group, passwd, chkconfig, rkhunter

When initially exploring with RkHunter; such was characterised with the following "Warnings" on the initial setup and scan; albeit not having found any indicators associated to known or listed rootkits.

Such were:

/usr/sbin/ifup                                  [ Warning ]

/usr/bin/chkconfig                              [ Warning ]

/usr/bin/egrep                                  [ Warning ]

/usr/bin/fgrep                                  [ Warning ]

/usr/bin/ldd                                    [ Warning ]

Checking for passwd file changes                [ Warning ]

Checking for group file changes                 [ Warning ]

Checking if SSH root access is allowed          [ Warning ]

Checking if SSH protocol v1 is allowed          [ Warning ]

Checking /dev for suspicious file types         [ Warning ]

https://askubuntu.com/questions/593240/rkhunter-psswd-and-group-file-changes-warning

[rkhunter warns about chkconfig](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/52768/rkhunter-warns-about-chkconfig)

Of regard; SSH was manually disabled on such stated device which might be the causation to the following or above SSH warning.  When working through the associated Ubuntu article; updating RkHunter got rid of the first five errors on that of a second scan.

What would be to process to therein triaging or investigating the above listed warnings irrespective and if someone could point me to any associative help articles, such would be informative being somewhat new to Linux.